# A-frame toggling entity visible component won't render 360 images

Tags: entity, aframe, scene, webvr

I'm trying to swap entities in my single page app to emulate scene switching using some test buttons that I generated. It works correctly for the 'scene3DModel' but when switching over to 'scene360', the 360 image set to the src of  won't render ??? 360 image renders correctly when other 'scenes' are commented out.

**Markup for 'scene' entities:**

```
  <a-entity id="sceneHome" visible="true">
      <a-sky color="#6EBAA7"></a-sky>
  </a-entity>  

  <a-entity id="scene360" visible="false">
      <a-sky src='url(/assets/360-photo.jpg)'></a-sky>
  </a-entity> 

  <a-entity id="scene3DModel" visible="false" gltfpostprocessing gltf-opaque update-sun fog="density:1.3; near:4.0;">
    <!-- procedural environment-->
    <a-entity environment="preset: yavapai; seed: 5; skyColor: #cbdff7; horizonColor: #d8e0ae; shadow: true; shadowSize: 25.0; lightPosition: 10 40 30; fog: 0.91; playArea: 1; ground:hills; groundYScale: 4; groundColor: #c69c7b; groundColor2: #c1a582; dressingAmount: 0; dressingUniformScale: false; grid: crosses; gridColor: #bb9977"></a-entity>
    <!-- scene lights--> 
    <a-entity light="type: ambient; color: #fffcf2; intensity: 0.6; "></a-entity>
    <!--3D Models-->
    <a-entity id="loaded-model" gltf-model="#temple-gltf" ></a-entity>
  </a-entity>
```

**Generated Markup for buttons -** 
Events are being emitted correctly

```
<a-entity view-toggle-test="" id="view-toggle" position="0 1 2" rotation="0 180 0" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2" visible="">
    <a-triangle position="0 0" text="value:image;color:red;width:4;align:center" rotation="" scale="" visible="" material="" geometry="height:0.1846484165324745;width:4;primitive:triangle"></a-triangle>
    <a-triangle position="0 1.5" text="value:home;color:red;width:4;align:center" rotation="" scale="" visible="" material="" geometry="height:0.1846484165324745;width:4;primitive:triangle"></a-triangle>
    <a-plane position="0 3" text="value:model;color:red;width:4;align:center" rotation="" scale="" visible="" material="" geometry=""></a-plane>
</a-entity>
```

**Scene manager component**

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('scene-manager', {
    schema: {
    },
    init: function (){
        var self = this
        var el = this.el;
        window.addEventListener('activeSceneChanged',(e)=> {
            nextScene = e.detail.activeScene;
            self.setScene(nextScene)
        });
    }, 
    setScene: function(nextScene){
        var sceneHome = document.getElementById('sceneHome');
        var scene360 = document.getElementById('scene360');
        var scene3DModel = document.getElementById('scene3DModel'); 

        //stupid version of swapping logic
        if(nextScene == 'sceneHome'){
            scene360.setAttribute('visible', 'false');
            scene3DModel.setAttribute('visible', 'false');
            sceneHome.setAttribute('visible', 'true');
        }if(nextScene == 'scene360'){
            sceneHome.setAttribute('visible', 'false');
            scene3DModel.setAttribute('visible', 'false');
            scene360.setAttribute('visible', 'true');
        }if(nextScene == 'scene3DModel'){
            sceneHome.setAttribute('visible', 'false');
            scene360.setAttribute('visible', 'false');
            scene3DModel.setAttribute('visible', 'true');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Environment settings from the environment component I'm using were overriding the a-sky 360.  I switched to k-frame templates for scene management and am toggling attribute --  environment, {active:false}